# no known class method for selector confusion

Tags: ios, ios5, core-data, automatic-ref-counting

I know this is a newbie question, but I am all confused. How should I call class method from another class, or shouldn't I?

Here is my `ClassA` and `CoreDataHelper`:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface ClassA : NSObject {

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * sessionId;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * token;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * userid;

+ (void) pullOfflineDataWithContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext ;
@end


#import "ClassA.h"
#import "CoreDataHelper.h"

@implementation ClassA


+ (void) pullOfflineDataWithContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext  {

    // get Contacts, Accounts, Meetings into Core Data

     bool asd =[CoreDataHelper insertAllObjectsForEntity:@"Contact" andContext:managedObjectContext initCoreData:jsonDict];

}
@end

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@interface CoreDataHelper : NSObject

//For inserting objects
+(BOOL)insertAllObjectsForEntity:(NSString*)entityName andContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext;

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling a class method from another in the right way except the method signature is not the same as it is declared;

```
bool asd =[CoreDataHelper insertAllObjectsForEntity:@"Contact" 
                                         andContext:managedObjectContext 
                                       initCoreData:jsonDict];
```

The declaration of +insertAllObjectsForEntity:andContext: does not have the last one in the calling code above

```
+(BOOL)insertAllObjectsForEntity:(NSString*)entityName 
                      andContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext;
```

Comment: but compiler should not warn me as "no known class method for selector"

Comment: @tugce Well, actually compiler is right according to Objective-C rule: +insertAllObjectsForEntity:andContext:initCoreData: makes one complete method signature that has quite similar semantic of 'symbol' in C.

Answer (score 0):

Like:

```
[ClassName method];
```

Instead of:

```
[instance method];
```

In your example would be then:

```
[ClassA pullOfflineDataWithContext];
```